# Arquivo sendo usado em outro processo

Tags: c#, visual-studio

De repente meu aplicativo começou a dar esse erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso começou essa semana, junto com um problema que estou tentando resolver em outro post. Começo a pensar que eles têm correlação. Esse dá, dou ok e ao dar F5 outra vez funciona, ou seja, para rodar meu aplicativo pelo VS2013, tenho que apertar o F5 duas vezes. A primeira dá erro e depois a segunda já funciona. Alguém já passou por isso e deseja compartilhar? No aguardo.

Comment: Só com estas informações não consigo ajudar, mas certamente tem a ver com aquelas coisas que eu falo pra todo mundo e as pessoas ignoram. As pessoas fazem o simples demais, não testam todas as possibilidades, mas parece funcionar. Um dia começa aparecer o problema porque o código estava errado. Neste caso específico é provável que algum arquivo foi aberto e não fechado. Tem o jeito certo de lidar com isso, mas eu vejo uma insistência em fazer do jeito errado. Obviamente só poderia afirmar com certeza e der mais detalhes se tivesse detalhes suficientes na pergunta.

Comment: Eu desabilitei o `Enabled Visual Studio hosting process`, rodei. Como isso gerou uns `Warnings` do visual, eu voltei a habilitar. Rodei sem o debug e quando eu voltei tudo como estava antes, não deu mais o problema. Inclusive o problema que relatei em outro post. Rodei 4 vezes seguida e não deu mais o problema. Zipei e já enviei para a homol da empresa. De qualquer forma agradeço a todos.

Comment: Antes de negativar ou imaginar que o código está errado, reparem que o erro é um lançado pelo Visual Studio. Vejam o título e o estilo da janela, não é uma exceção lançada pela aplicação do AP, possivelmente não é um erro do código do AP. Se você costuma programar em C# e utilizar o Visual Studio, deveria perceber a diferença. @pnet, é possível que o Visual Studio não estivesse conseguindo sobrescrever algum arquivo ou deletar um diretório durante o build; talvez o aplicativo já estivesse em execução ou uma janela do prompt de comando do Windows estivesse ocupando o diretório.

Comment: Eu já sofri com este tipo de instabilidade no Visual Studio (a aplicação uma vez compilada funcionava perfeitamente) e resolvi reorganizando alguma referência no projeto... Infelizmente já faz muitos anos e não me lembro exatamente o que era - lembro que era um projeto que usava muito ActiveX... Veja [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818076/why-do-i-get-file-is-used-by-another-process-errors-when-i-debug-within-visual) como várias pessoas tiveram problemas semelhantes por várias causas distintas.

Comment: @Caffé, pode ser isso mesmo. Pois ao rodar a aplicação, ao fim de tudo deveria fechar tudo, porem, mesmo a aplicação sendo finalizada, ainda assim continua o visual rodando. Tenho que ir manualmente e dar um kill no VS(quando deveria ser automática): `Application.Current.Shutdown();` Esse é o comando que dou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu desabilitei o `Enabled Visual Studio hosting process`, rodei. Como isso gerou uns `Warnings` do visual, eu voltei a habilitar. Rodei sem o `debug` e quando eu voltei tudo como estava antes, não deu mais o problema. Inclusive o problema que relatei em outro post. Rodei 4 vezes seguida e não deu mais o problema. Zipei e já enviei para a homol da empresa. De qualquer forma agradeço a todos.